# Задано натуральное х, необходимо вывести все простые натуральные числа, которые меньше х

Tags: c++, простые-числа

Буду рад, если поможете и скажете, где проблема в коде:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    cin >> n;

  while ( i<=n )
  {
      if ( i%2 != 0 && i%2 != 0 && i%2 != 0 )
      {
       cout<<'prime number are: '<< i << endl; 
      }
      else 
      {
          return 0;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что кода проверки на простоту у вас нет.
Вторая проблема - бесконечный цикл.

Comment: А третья проблема - не инциализированная переменная?

Comment: Чтобы найти простые числа меньше заданного, можно [решето Эратосфена использовать](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#C.2B.2B)

Comment: можна код плс ?

Answer (score 3):

*Проще* всего, пожалуй, примерно так:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int N;
    cin >> N;
    if (N <= 2) return 0;
    cout << "2\n";
    vector<bool> p(N,true);
    p[0] = p[1] = false;
    for(unsigned int i = 4; i < N; i+= 2) p[i] = false;
    for(unsigned int j = 3; j < N; j+=2)
    {
        if (p[j] == false) continue;
        cout << j << "\n";
        if (j*j < N) for(unsigned int i = 2; i*j < N; ++i) p[i*j] = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    vector<bool> arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    arr.push_back(true);

    for (int i = 2; i < x; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i])
        {
            cout << i << " ";
            for (int j = i; j < x; j = j + i)
            arr[j] = false;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А зачем вы `arr[i]` после провеки делаете `false`? Пусть массив уже не нужен, но зачем его портить?

Comment: @Mikhailo `arr[j] = false;` ? Так я задаю всем числам, которые делятся на `i` значение `false`, а если вы про то, что я не написал `for (int j = i + i; j < x; j = j + i)` - то вы совершенно правы.